# Windows: How do I find all instances of hidden folder and delete?

Tags: windows, command-line, cmd.exe, file-management

My backup software when it backups up a file share it injects a bunch of hidden folders with meta data about the files in every single folder and its children. There are hundreds of this folder name called `.nt_streams`.

I recently had to restore from backup and now all my files have this hidden directory everywhere. How can I use the CMD prompt to recursively scan through the entire folder hierarchy and remove this folder and the files inside of it?

I've looked around and can't find a consistent answer. Some people using for files, some using find, etc.

Here is an example of the structure:

```
Root Folder/
    .nt_steams/
    Folder1/
    Folder2/
        .nt_steams/
        Folder1
            .nt_streams/
                Folder1
                    .nt_streams/
                    File1
    Folder3/
        .nt_steams/
        File1
        File2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

powershell

```
$folder = ".nt_streams"
$rootdir = "*root folder*"

$folders = gci $rootdir -recurse | where {$_.name -match $folder}

foreach($item in $folders){remove-item $item -force -whatif}
```

Remove the -whatif once you've run it once and confirmed that it is only targeting what you expect it to.

Comment: Worked, thanks. I did modify it slightly to be a one-liner though.

`Get-ChildItem "Z:\folder\path" -Force -Recurse | Where-Object {$_.name -eq ".nt_streams"} | Remove-Item -Force -Recurse`